# lost property when expand uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have a property that is an image in a cell expands,when the pulse in the cell assigned a selectedIndexPath you change the height in the corresponding method , and I want that image to change when the cell is expanded, the problem is that when I expand the cell changes but the image is returned to the previous one that happens when I throw animation to expand the cell is repainted.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];

IACCell *cell =  (IACCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if(!self.selectedIndexPath||![self.selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]){

    self.selectedIndexPath=indexPath;
    tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];

}else{
    self.selectedIndexPath=nil;
    tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;


}
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

}

the cell.imageView.Image changes briefly and the problem I think is in [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];,
anyone can help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to maintain these values in your datasource, not on the views themselves. So in cellForRow you can then check the datasource and display the cell as you want.

Comment: thank you very much friend, already solved, was that the problem had to to abstract more